# Declare optional dependencies within extras_require

Tags: python, pip, dependencies, setuptools

I have a package with `extras_require` which depend on the `extras_require` of another package. For example:

```py
setup(
    name="my-package",
    install_requires=["other-package==1.0.0"],  # Base package, no advanced features
    extras_require={"advanced": ["other-package[advanced]==1.0.0"]},  # Advanced features
    ...
)
```

From the [setuptools docs](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#id20), I would have assumed that the above would work, given:

> Projects can also use another project’s extras when specifying dependencies. For example, if project B needs “project A” with PDF support installed, it might declare the dependency like this:

```py
setup(
    name="Project-B",
    install_requires=["Project-A[PDF]"],
    ...
)
```

It seems, however, that the dependencies declared under `install_requires` override those in `extras_require` and no matter how I install this package (e.g. `pip install .[advanced]`), I do not get the `other-package[advanced]` dependencies.

Is this an expected limitation? And is there a nice way to get this working as intended (i.e. `pip install .[advanced]` also installs `other-package[advanced]`)? (I'm guessing it might involve writing a custom `setuptools` class?)

Comment: These days _pip_'s team is working on writing a new dependency solver. They might be interested in hearing about this kind of issues. Maybe start reading here: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8099 -- and raise an issue here: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues

Answer (score 2):

`install_requires` list **requirements**, `extras_require` lists **recommendations**. So `install_requires` always wins. The only way to implement what you want is to avoid hard requirements at all, list everything in `extras_require`:

```
setup(
    name="my-package",
    extras_require={
        "advanced": ["other-package[advanced]==1.0.0"]},  # Advanced features
        "simple": ["other-package==1.0.0"]},  # Basic features
    ...
)
```

and teach users to run either `pip install .[simple]` or `pip install .[advanced]` but not `pip install .`